# Addition of number with decimal values are not working with parseFloat

Tags: javascript

i have 2 numbers with decimals

```
var a = 455.7530
var b = 544.8025

var k = parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b)

Expected Output is 1000.5555
Actual Output is 1000.5554999999999
```

Please advice which method i should use to add two numbers with decimal

Comment: the values are already floats/numbers. welcome to the wonderful world of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: it is float only

Comment: Have you tried `k.toFixed(4)` ?